# Why Tftp won't work globally?

Tags: linux, networking, port-forwarding, tftp, tftpd

I have `tftpd-hpa` with `inetd` installed.

Locally (`tftp <ip-address>`) works fine.

Port 69 is opened and worked both on input and output.

Using

```
netcat -ul -p 69
```

I can track incoming file, and yes - incoming file is correct both with size and name.

Configuration is default from every manual

```
tftp  dgram   udp     wait    root  /usr/sbin/tcpd  in.tftpd /tftpboot
```

Mode `777` and owner is `nobody`, while `tftpd-hpa` and `openbsd` both are `root`.

Thx

Comment: In the question, you mention that something works. What is the issue? And what do you mean by "`tftpd-hpa` and `openbsd` both are `root`"?

Comment: welcome to U&L, can you be more specific about "won't work" and "globally" ?

Comment: tftpd-hpa and openbsd users in their configs are root. Using tftp installed in system I can get and put files locally. But from other machines I can't reach tftp server. Most possible reason, I think, is in ownership of files and tftpboot folder. But I can't find out it

Comment: If you can't reach from other machines owner are irrevellant. I would suspect firewall, NAT or routing issue. can you post an edited output of `ip r s` of local and remote host ? (you don't need to edit 192.168.X.Y)

Comment: I can reach them with ssh and ping. Firewall disabled. I did it, but only if users and owners are setted to root (tftp, nobody - doesn't work).

Comment: The TFTP protocol doesn't have a concept of user accounts, so everything readable by TFTP is effectively world-readable; likewise, anything writable by TFTP is effectively writable by anyone who can contact the server port. Since you have `/usr/sbin/tcpd` in the configuration, tcpwrapper is in effect: check `/etc/hosts.allow` and `/etc/hosts.deny` files for any settings applying to `in.tftpd`.

Comment: Nothing about in.tftpd hosts. Why tftp doesn't have concept of users? You are setting tftp user in tftp options and for it's daemon and I believe this is kind of user concept. Maybe not user, but user permission. Maybe you know, how to get rid of using full path for uploading files to tftp? (not using just file name, but /tftpboot/file)?